# Surprising result from Math.pow(65,17) % 3233

Tags: java, double, modulo, largenumber

For some reason when dealing with large numbers, the modulus operator doesnt give me the correct output, have a look at the code

```
double x = Math.pow(65,17) % 3233;
```

The output is supposed to be `2790`
But the output is `887.0`

I am sure its something silly but i cant get around it. Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a homework problem because 65**17 is just barely too large to fit into a 64-bit long. So, do some thinking before you go asking here on SO!

Comment: -1 for saying the modulus operator is at fault, vs admitting from the start that it was almost certainly your misunderstanding that was at fault.

Answer (score 7):

The result of `Math.pow(65, 17)` cannot be represented exactly as a `double`, and is getting rounded to the nearest number that can.

The `pow(a, b) % c` operation is called "modular exponentiation". The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) contains lots of ideas for how you might go about computing it.

Here is one possibility:

```
public static int powmod(int base, int exponent, int modulus) {
    if (exponent < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("exponent < 0");
    int result = 1;
    while (exponent > 0) {
        if ((exponent & 1) != 0) {
            result = (result * base) % modulus;
        }
        exponent >>>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @micha: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Doh, sorry. I don't know why i was thinking about javascript. Deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use int like this

```
int n = 65;
for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
    n = n * 65 % 3233;
System.out.println(n);
```

or BigInteger like

```
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(65).pow(17).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(3233)));
```

both print

```
2790
```